# Would I use dispatch in block for MBProgressHud?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform, mbprogresshud

In the MBProgressHud documentation it states to use this inside of a dispatch like so:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Which is completely understandable considering you don't want it to boggle up the main thread. But could I just do this instead when using a block:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (error)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                }
            }];
```

Or would I still have to use dispatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to be like this:

```
 [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
 [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Am I running on the main thread: %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES": @"NO");
         if (error)
         {

         }
         else
         {

         }
   }];
```

if it logs "YES" then you don't need to run `[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];` on the main thread, otherwise you need to use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
});
```

**Update:**

blocks are run on whatever thread they've been called from, notice following example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self longRunningProcessWithCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Is running on the main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }];
}



- (void)longRunningProcessWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))completionBlock {

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    //this is running on the concurrent thread, so does completionBlock() as it has been called on a concurrent thread.
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
        completionBlock();
    });
}
```

So Basically the result of above will be `"Is running on the main thread? NO"`

Again I have exact same call on `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self longRunningProcessWithCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Is running on the main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }];
}
```

But this time, I'm calling `completionBlock` of `longRunningProcessWithCompletionBlock` on the main thread as follow:

```
- (void)longRunningProcessWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))completionBlock {

    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];

        //notice the difference, this time we are calling the completionBlock on the main thread, so that block will be running on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock();
        });

    });
}
```

This time because we have called the completion block on the main thread, the result will be `Is running on the main thread? YES`

So in a nutshell, block does not guarantee that they are getting executed on the main thread! but they can guarantee that they will be executed on whatever thread they've been called from.

In your case `Parse.com` developers are calling the completion handler block of `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock` on the main thread and that's why you saw that log was "yes".So you just need to call `[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];` without `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ });` (as it is already on the main thread and this is an extra unnecessary step)

Comment: It did log yes, so that block is being ran on the main thread? Now I'm confused. I thought blocks were separate from the main thread so that it doesn't lock up the UI?

Comment: Great thanks for the explanation. So I take it the Parse background blocks are done on a seperate thread as far as pulling data, and then in the completion part is where I would update the UI? (without worrying about GCD since it's already on main thread)

Comment: Exactly right. I assume somewhere in their documentation they must have mentioned it. Anyways, using "NSLog(@"Is running on the main thread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO");" approach  always helps to determine which thread has called the completion handler.